# Изменить параметры шаблона функции внутри шаблонного класса

Tags: c++

У меня есть класс красно-чёрного дерева, построенного на шаблонах:

```
template<class T>
class  RBTree
{
public:
    RBTree();
    ~RBTree();

    void insert(T key);    // Insert node, key is the key value, external interface
    void remove(T key); // Delete the node of the key
    RBTNode<T>* search(T key);
    void print();
    void preOrder();    // Pre - order traversal Print red black tree
    void inOrder();    //Intermediate traversal
    void postOrder();    // Post - order traversal



private:
    void leftRotate(RBTNode<T>* &root, RBTNode<T>* x);// left-handed
    void rightRotate(RBTNode<T>* &root, RBTNode<T>* y);// right handed

    void insert(RBTNode<T>* &root, RBTNode<T>* node);// insert node, internal interface
    void InsertFixUp(RBTNode<T>* &root, RBTNode<T>* node);
    void destory(RBTNode<T>* &node);

    void remove(RBTNode<T>*& root, RBTNode<T>*node); // Delete the node as KEY
    void removeFixUp(RBTNode<T>* &root, RBTNode<T>* node, RBTNode<T>*parent);

    RBTNode<T>* search(RBTNode<T>*node, T key) const;
    void print(RBTNode<T>* node)const;
    void preOrder(RBTNode<T>* tree)const;
    void inOrder(RBTNode<T>* tree)const;
    void postOrder(RBTNode<T>* tree)const;
private:
    RBTNode<T>*root;
};
```

Я бы хотел позволить некоторым функциями, например, `insert()` принимать ещё и второй параметр с помощью шаблона, то есть изменить объявление функции внутри класса на

```
template<class T,typename R> 
void insert(T key,R info);
```

никак не изменяя начало класса:

```
template<class T>
class  RBTree
{
public:
...
```

Соответственно, в определении функции написать уже вместо такого:

```
template<class T>       //insert
void RBTree<T>::insert(T key)
{
    RBTNode<T>*z = new RBTNode<T>(key, Red, NULL, NULL, NULL);
    insert(root, z);
};
```

Вот это :

```
    template<class T,class R>       //insert
void RBTree<T>::insert(T key,R info)
{
    RBTNode<T>*z = new RBTNode<T>(key, Red, NULL, NULL, NULL,info);
    insert(root, z);
};
```

Но мне не удаётся так сделать по причине такой ошибки -отсутствуют экземпляры перегруженная функция "RBTree::insert", соответствующие заданному типу

Можно ли вообще так делать? Если да, то как?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
template<class T>
class  RBTree {
public:
  template<class R> 
  void insert(T key,R info); 
// ...
}

template<class T>
template<class R>
void RBTree<T>::insert(T key,R info) {
    RBTNode<T>*z = new RBTNode<T>(key, Red, NULL, NULL, NULL,info);
    insert(root, z);
};
```

ЗЫ: не стоит забывать, что у `RBTNode` также должен быть шаблонный конструктор. Синтаксис у него аналогичный.